# Nested hierarchy view (for comment system)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'd like to implement a commenting system where users can reply to others who've left comments. I'd like to display these comments in a nested hierarchy view, similar to what the reddit app "Apollo" does below:

https://i.imgur.com/JiLLsjs.mp4

As you can see, the comments are sorted in a nested format.

Here is what my API response looks like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "comments": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "parent_id": 0,
                    "depth": 0,
                    "message": "1",
                    "children_count": 2,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "parent_id": 1,
                            "depth": 1,
                            "message": "2",
                            "children_count": 1,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "parent_id": 2,
                                    "depth": 2,
                                    "message": "3",
                                    "children_count": 0,
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "parent_id": 1,
                            "depth": 1,
                            "message": "2",
                            "children_count": 0,
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "parent_id": 0,
                    "depth": 0,
                    "message": "1",
                    "children_count": 0,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, each `comment` object has a `parent_id` (the parent comment ID), a `depth` (basically the "level" of the comment in the hierarchy), a `children_count` (the number of direct children), and `children` (the children comments themselves).

So with that, my questions are:

1. How would this best be implemented? As a table view, collection view, or something else? I assume I would create a xib for the comment view itself?
2. What is the best way to approach actually implementing this? How should I loop through the API response?
3. How do I add a margin/padding to the left side to make a comment look nested?
4. How do I make the cells expandable?
5. What should I know about in terms of memory management?

Thanks.

Comment: Beyond "too broad", all the way to "insanely broad".

Comment: What am I supposed to do when I'm not sure where to start? I've given enough specific questions to make things clearer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- Personally would go with a tableView

2- It's a recursive operation that ends with `let children: [Datum]?` being empty/nil like

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct Root: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let comments: Comments
}

// MARK: - Comments
struct Comments: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let id, parentID, depth: Int
    let message: String
    let childrenCount: Int
    let children: [Datum]?
}
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder() 
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let res = decoder.decode(Root.self, from:data)
```

3- You need to limit the number of replies to a comment , as there is no screen width will fit for un-known number of replies btw it's about nested tableView padding

4- You need to play with `heightForRowAt` or you'll have to do some calculations for the nested tables or better fixed height with more , also more easier is to show nested comments inside another separate vc and so like facebook

5- Simply don't nest multiple vcs over each other with a count more than 2/3 also using table cells are dequeued which is a good memory performance handled automatically by system

Comment: Would each table view cell hold another table view with another table view cell for each nested comment?

Comment: personally i think it's enough to nest only 1/2 tables more than this should open in a new table vc